# Solving $\frac{4}{3} = \frac{3.2}{y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

This is what I've tried.

$\frac{1}{3.2} \cdot \frac{4}{3} = \frac{3.2}{y} \cdot \frac{1}{3.2}$ to isolate $y$ via product and quotient identity.

When simplified this gives me $\frac{4}{9.6} = y$ so $y = 0.41\overline{6}$

However, the textbook gives an answer of $y=2.4$ and in the example they used the cross-product method which does follow, but what I did should also give me the same answer.

Comment: It should be $\dfrac{4}{9.6}=\dfrac{1}{y}$

Comment: Multiplying with $y$ would have avoided this mistake. Even better is multiplying with $3y$ to "clear the denominators". Some care is needed if we choose this way because $y=0$ is forbidden, but the result is fortunately not $0$.

Comment: @Peter thanks, that's the way I wanted to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you multiply $\dfrac{1}{3.2}$ both side:
$$\dfrac{1}{3.2}\times\dfrac{4}{3}=\dfrac{3.2}{y}\times\dfrac{1}{3.2}\\\dfrac{4}{9.6}=\dfrac{1}{y}\\\dfrac{1}{2.4}=\dfrac{1}{y}\\y=\boxed{2.4}$$

Another way to do this is to use cross method:
$$\dfrac{4}{3}=\dfrac{3.2}{y}\\ 4y=3.2\times 3 \\4y=9.6 \\ y=\boxed{2.4}$$

Answer (score 1):

You arrive at $$\frac{4}{3\cdot 3.2}=\frac{1}{y}$$ so the correct result is the reciprocal of your result

Answer (score 1):

When you got as far as
$$
\frac{1}{y} = \frac{4}{3.2 \times 3}
$$
(which is correct) you thought the left side was the same as $y$.